# Attaching a volume to multiple instances with Amazon EBS Multi-Attach and share the Volume in multiple instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am sharing AWS a Volume (Volume) to multiple EC2 instances (Instance A and Instance B).

[Instance A]

```
root@ip-xxx-xx-59-75:/data# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        8065444 2405580   5643480  30% /
devtmpfs         1986800       0   1986800   0% /dev
tmpfs            1990908       8   1990900   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             398184     820    397364   1% /run
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            1990908       0   1990908   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme1n1   102687672   61468  97366940   1% /data   <----- Same Volume
/dev/loop1         99328   99328         0 100% /snap/core/9665
/dev/loop0         28800   28800         0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2012
/dev/loop2         56320   56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop3         56704   56704         0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop4         73088   73088         0 100% /snap/lxd/16100
/dev/loop5         73216   73216         0 100% /snap/lxd/16530
tmpfs             398180       0    398180   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs             398180       0    398180   0% /run/user/1000
```

[Instance B]

```
root@ip-xxx-xx-54-217:/home/ubuntu# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        8065444 2368588   5680472  30% /
devtmpfs         1986800       0   1986800   0% /dev
tmpfs            1990908       8   1990900   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             398184     828    397356   1% /run
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            1990908       0   1990908   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme1n1   102687672   61468  97366940   1% /data   <----- Same Volume
/dev/loop0         28800   28800         0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2012
/dev/loop1         99328   99328         0 100% /snap/core/9665
/dev/loop2         56320   56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop3         56704   56704         0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop4         73088   73088         0 100% /snap/lxd/16100
/dev/loop5         73216   73216         0 100% /snap/lxd/16530
tmpfs             398180       0    398180   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs             398180       0    398180   0% /run/user/1000
```

Both instances are using the same Volume.
I created a file (test.html) in Instance A. But I couldn't see the same file Instance B.
If I reboot the Instance B, then I can see the test.html.

Is there any way we can share the same files instantly to Multiple at the same time (Instance A and B) without reboot?

Comment: I wonder whether something was being cached by the Operating System? Did you try accessing the file by name, even though it wasn't listed?

Comment: [The operation of standard file systems on EBS Multi-Attach volumes isn't a supported configuration.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-access-volumes-using-multi-attach/)  What kind of filesystem is on this volume?

Comment: I used "ext4" but I am not sure if it's right decision. I don't know the difference. Should I use the different filesystem? Thanks.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: just use aws EFS

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a filesystem / app that's multi-attach aware. For example Oracle RAC can use such volumes, while normal filesystems like ext4 or xfs can't. They are designed to be mounted on a single host only.

Let's step back - what are you trying to achieve? Share files between the instances I suppose? Your best bet is [EFS (Elastic File System)](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) - an AWS cloud-native NFS service. Unless you've got a very specific need for multi-attach EBS and running some very special app that can make use of that I suggest you explore the EFS way instead. The need for multi-attach disks is rare, both in the cloud and outside.